# configuring php with oracle usin tns on mac os x

Tags: php, oracle, macos

I am new to php but I've got it running (php 5.3.3) on my mac (OS 10.6). However when I try to run this script:

```
    <?php // Create connection to Oracle
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "tnsnames.ora");
if (!$conn) {
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else {
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}
// Close the Oracle connection
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

I get the error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()..."

Now, I've checked oracle's website and downloaded their instant client, but I'm stuck as to what to do next.  Their instructions are:

> On non-Windows platforms rebuild PHP
>   using the following configuration
>   option:
>   --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/libs
>   Edit your php.ini file and add:
>   extension = oci8.so Ensure that your
>   extension_dir parameter (in php.ini)
>   points to the location where oci8.so
>   was installed. Set environment
>   variables required by Oracle, such as
>   PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (on
>   Linux) Restart you webserver.

But could someone explain that to me in simpler language?  I am really confused.  I can't find an oci8.so file in the instant client folder, and I don't know where to put the extention = oci8.so in the file (all I have are php.ini-production and php.ini-development.  And I don't know how "rebuild" PHP with configuration options.

Oh and I don't know how to pull in the tnsnames.org file either.  Is this the right way?  Since I don't even have a connection yet, I don't know if this is failing or not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the filename "tnsnames.ora" in your oci_connect call. You want the name of a database connection alias *in the tnsnames.ora file*. The tnsnames.ora file contains a list of known database connection entires, identified by aliases. For a database alias named "db_alias", you would use this call:

```
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "db_alias");
```

A typical tnsnames.ora entry would look something like this:

```
DB_NAME =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = foo.bar.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE = some_db_service_name))
  )
```

Alternatively, you can use an Easy Connect string:

```
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "//host:port/db_service_name");
```

Where host, port and db_service_name are to be replaced by values from your environment. So, for host "foo" with database "bar" on standard port 1521, your connection would look like this:

```
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "//foo:1521/bar");
```

Have a look at the [manual page for oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually tried just using the tnsnames.ora file as a string, but I can't tell if that worked either because of the "Call to undefined function oci_connect()" error.  So I need to configure php first before I test this out.

Comment: Have look at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=406036&start=15&tstart=0 and look for the post by codrai.

Comment: that post by codrai is for Windows and I'm using a mac.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with a full connect string:

```
$rnum=rand(0,99999999);
$connect_str = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = $dbserver) (PORT = $dbport) (HASH = '.$rnum.') ) (CONNECT_DATA =(SID = $dbname)) )";
$DB = oci_connect($dbuser, $dbpass, $connect_str);
```

Works like a charm for me.